# Rendering of django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus widget on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, django-forms, bootstrap-datepicker

I wrote a very simple django application and uploaded it to pythonanywhere. Through [this](https://github.com/ruggerod/game_night/blob/master/board/templates/board/session_form.html) form (and its base [template](https://github.com/ruggerod/game_night/blob/master/templates/base.html)) I'd like to allow the user to setting date and time using [django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus](https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus) (and [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3)).

**The date-picker widget works fine on my localhost** in debugging mode (see a detail of my [local] webpage in this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCNve.png)), i.e. I can click on the calendar icon to display the calendar widget. **My problem is that on the pythonanywhere server the widget cannot be displayed** (i.e., the calendar icon is missing and when I click on the rightmost part of the date-time entry field, nothing happens).

I am using the **same source code** (pulling the latest versions of my github repository). Moreover, the virtual environment on pythonanywhere is set through a requirement.txt file obtained by [pip] freezing my local environment (thus, I am also using the **same python packages**).

Comment: Hey ruggero, please have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in order to help us help you. Right now you require people who'd like to help you to visit multiple websites and the link to pythonanywhere leads to a login page. [Please include a Minimal, Complete and Verifieable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @Maurice, I forgot that the webpage needed a logged-in user. I updated my question trying to describe the problem with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely issue is that you're not serving the static files that are necessary for the widget to work. Check your browser requests in the developer tools to see if you're getting 404s for any resources that may be used by the widget. If they are 404ing, have a look at the PythonAnywhere and Django docs for how to properly serve static resources.

Comment: Thanks @Glenn for your help. The problem was related to the static files of bootstrap_datepicker_plus. In pythonanywhere I need to specify the static files path manually. Thus, I used "/static/bootstrap_datepicker_plus/" as URL and something like to "/home/<my_username>/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bootstrap_datepicker_plus/static/bootstrap_datepicker_plus" as Directory.  This solved my problem